# Is it typical for self-answered questions to be downvoted?

Tags: discussion, design, answers, down-votes, self-answer

As a habit, I have always tried to answer my own questions on Stack Overflow and other sites if no one provided an answer, and I later found the answer myself. I consider this to be essential to helping other developers in the future. Some examples:

- Lack of support of TailwindCSS in webkit browsers [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66665996/apparent-lack-of-support-for-tailwind-css-2-on-webkit-based-browsers)
- Vim replace regex command [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66857884/vim-regex-to-search-up-to-a-string)
- Material theme lack of support for dark theme [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/613396/gnome-materia-theme-help)

I'd admit that many of the original questions I answered were not the best questions. They were often the result of poor research and/or I could have found the answers if I looked hard enough into documentation for long enough. **What I would like to stress, however, is that my impression of SO is a site of sharing knowledge.** I would really not mind if my *questions* were downvoted, because of their lack of merit. What I do not understand is why it seems like **knowledge-sharing through self-answering** is starting to become discouraged.

Comment: *I'd admit that many of the original questions I answered were not the best questions.* That is what I thought so I downvoted them. Was that wrong? The down vote tool tip says that I can use that button when a question is unclear, not useful or lacks research. Am I misunderstanding the usage of that particular button?

Comment: My impression of SO is [*we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.*](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) I admit that doesn't exclude sharing knowledge but that doesn't mean that all knowledge that can be shared is well received.

Comment: I'm wondering where you got that knowledge sharing impression from. If you can find a reference would you mind sharing it? Maybe the blog defines it so overly broad.

Comment: Self-answering is not in the least discouraged -- provided you do it correctly: by entering the answer in the answer field to answer your own question, and accepting that answer instead of providing a notice in the question body as plain text.

Comment: @rene I have no issues in the fact that you downvoted my questions, and you are using it as you should - to keep SO an orderly QA site. And yes, I got the impression of SO as a knowledge sharing site from the blog, where the idea of knowledge-sharing was referenced quite often.

Comment: Sharing knowledge, yes, definitely. We all want that. Once the knowledge is shared though, the value of a site like SO is the repository of existing Q&A - the "shared knowledge base" if you will. Google something programming-related, find exactly what you need right away. Multiply by a few millions of times every day. If low-quality Q&As make up the bulk of the knowledge that's shared on the site, then the higher-quality Q&As get drowned in a sea of uselessness, and everybody loses...

Comment: I don't think this is a very good duplicate closure. This question specifically addresses whether, why, and when self-answered questions are typically downvoted (and one of the answers even provides data on it).  The linked question mostly addresses other forms of moderation of such questions.  They're related, but distinct.  Thus, I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Self-Answer**

The main reasons for self-answered questions to be downvoted typically have nothing to do with a discouraging attitude towards self-answering. Instead, as pointed out above, these are the most common:

- The question simply happens to be unclear, not useful or lacking original research. Even if the answer is good, that doesn't *necessarily* mean that the question would be good as well - hence the downvote
- The answer does not conform to [good answer guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). As such, it is downvoted, because it does not improve the experience of those accessing SO as a whole, nor adds to the existing body of knowledge on the site
- The answer is not formatted correctly, such as being in the question body, composed with excessive formatting (e.g. all bold), or is hard to find
- On many Stack Exchange sites, not just Stack Overflow, a vague answer, one given without sufficient detail, or one too broad to be applicable to the issue in question could also get a downvote

It is important to note that sharing knowledge, or having as many answers as possible, is **not the function of Stack Overflow**. Rather, the function of Stack Overflow is to selectively pick out the best questions and answers. As such, self-answered questions are like treated like any other question, and self-answers are also treated likewise.

If your answer is downvoted, it does not mean the answer is wrong, inaccurate, or the person answering it does not deserve their share of credit. In contrast, take it as positive criticism, and a way to help everyone ask better questions.

Comment: Exactly.  Upvoted your self-answer ;)

Comment: If there are no issues with the above answer, I would appreciate it if someone could approve it; personally, I believe it is beneficial if other users could see that the issue is closed, and that there *is* an answer as opposed to simply suggestions and comments.

Comment: The answer above looks like a fine one:  It answers the question (correctly), has some good reasons for downvotes, so... approved?

Comment: If you mean "accepted", then only the question asker can do that. In this case, that's you, so if you think the answer answers your question, you can accept it yourself.

Comment: @cigien Thank you for the clarification. As per SO policy, I cannot accept the question until after two days (see https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/). Instead, I thought a moderator had the authority to be able to accept an answer; that was why I suggested that above.

Comment: @JS4137 don't worry, acceptance (especially in the case of self-answers) is not that important.

Comment: This is answer is too centered on SO, as this Meta SE it would be nice if it includes other sites.

Comment: @Rubén I added another point to address the issue you pointed out

Answer (score 14):

> Is it typical for self-answered questions to be downvoted?

We can even answer that with the help of the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). It took me a while because there's such a vast number of questions on Stack Overflow, but [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1394657/downvotes-on-self-answered-questions) shows self-answered questions are downvoted *less* often on average, and still only in 11% of the cases:

|  | Total | Average score | Average # of downvotes | % downvoted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All questions | 21067186 | 2.13 | 0.23 | 14 |
| Self-answered | 2231823 | 2.19 | 0.17 | 11 |

Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning, but for analysis like this that doesn't really matter. It doesn't include deleted posts (which often have downvotes), that might have an influence but it's hard to tell how significant. Have a look at the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) if you're new to SEDE and/or SQL in general.

Comment: By the way, I am amazed at the fact that more than 10% of the questions on Stack Overflow are self-answered. It felt more like 2 or 3% to me. (FWIW, I answered half of my own SO questions; I'm well aware that I'm an exception, I'm not good at asking questions.)

Comment: Which is *interesting*, since that means that 10% find the answer themselves, and bother to post and share with the commons

Comment: It begs the question whether it is the vote total or downvotes. How does it work? What is that type 3 vote type thing? Is every vote cast available in SEDE (including time and type (down/up))?

Comment: Some (possibly significant) percentage of those self answers would be OP who uses an answer as addendum to the question incorrectly. 10% seems very high though. Does that query included ones that were deleted due to using answer incorrectly and being asked to edit question instead?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q every vote cast is available in SEDE (but when an account is deleted, the votes they've given are deleted too, just like reflected in the post score and the OP's reputation). `3` is downvotes (that's what the comment is trying to convey) but the score includes upvotes as well.

Comment: @charlietfl yes, some of those self-answers could qualify as Not An Answer but are simply not deleted. It's hard to tell how many with SEDE; perhaps somebody is willing to do a random sampling of, say, 100 self-answered questions on SO and extrapolate the results.

Comment: This did get me wondering about what percentage of self answers are "direct" SA's, where the asker came and posted the Q & A at the same time, and what percentage have answers posted later by OP. That should be directly answerable through SEDE, I'm gonna give it a shot.

Comment: @zcoop98 that would be interesting, but note that some users don't see the 'instant self-answer' option and post it only 1-10+ minutes later.

Comment: I finally got it here: [Self-Answer Time Posted Stats](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1395165/self-answer-time-posted-stats). It looks like only ~7% of self answers are answered by OP "immediately" (within 15 minutes). About 20% are SA'd within the first hour, and 56% within the 24 hours.

Comment: Mildly related, but exploring this in SEDE exposed me to the weird phenomena of answers posted before their parent question ([query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1395189)). Most (?) of them can be explained by merges, but some of them have no merges in either the question or answer timelines, or have "answer" as the first event on their timeline, *before* "asked". [This Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258851/what-guidance-should-we-give-people-asking-unclear-questions-on-stack-overflow/258852#258852) on Meta.SO is an example of both.

Comment: @zcoop98 those are interesting stats (about self-answers) and perhaps worth featuring in another Q&A ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329143/4751173)). About the answers being older than the question, that's really funny. I love how the bottom of [this timeline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/258851/timeline) looks. The question was migrated but that doesn't seem to matter; [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJ0Hw.png) is its full timeline on Meta.SE. Perhaps they originally belonged on another question but staff has moved them to a different question.

Comment: (That happens rarely, e.g. in recent times they switched the owner of a post to another staff member so that something which was a self-answer could be accepted and remain pinned to the top - it was a rather unpopular answer.)